# FormView with EntityDataSource and DropDownList gives "A property names '{0}' was not found on the entity ..."

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, webforms

**The problem:** when I try to do an update using an `EntityDataSource` and a `FormView` that has an `<asp:DropDownList>` linking to another table, the page loads fine with the proper setting, but on update I get this error message:

> *A property named 'Vendor.VendorId' was not found on the entity during an insert, update, or delete operation. Check to ensure that properties specified as binding expressions are available to the data source.*

**The environment and code:** using Visual Studio 2010, Entity Framework 4, ASP.NET web forms, and SQL Server 2008 Express.

I have two tables; a `Part` table and a `Vendor` table. The `Part` table has a `VendorId` column which links to the `Vendor` table, and it is allowed to be `NULL`. It is wrapped by  Entity Framework.

**The part that works:**  here's the `EntityDataSource`:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="PartEntityDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=PartDBEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="PartDBEntities" EnableFlattening="True" 
    EntitySetName="Parts" 
    EntityTypeFilter="Part" Where="it.PartId = @PartId" 
    EnableUpdate="True" EnableInsert="True" Include="Vendor">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Type="Int64" DefaultValue="null" Name="PartId" 
            QueryStringField="partid" />
        </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

(Note: I've tried with `EnableFlattening` on and off.)

This is linked to by a `FormView`:

```
<asp:FormView ID="PartEditorFormView" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="PartEntityDataSource"
    DataKeyNames="PartId">
```

Note that I am forcing the `FormView` into `Edit` mode or `Insert` mode depending on a query string parameters.

Without the `DropDownList`, I am able to create and update records in the database.

**The part that doesn't work:** now for the `DropDownList`. First there is a new `EntityDataSource`:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="VendorEntityDataSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="name=PartDBEntities"
    DefaultContainerName="PartDBEntities" EnableFlattening="False"
    EntitySetName="Vendors" />
```

And then the `DropDownList` in the `EditTemplate`, using [Converting Null in Template Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366709.aspx):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="EditVendorDDL" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="VendorEntityDataSource" 
    DataTextField='CompanyName' 
    DataValueField='VendorId'
    AppendDataBoundItems="True"
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Vendor.VendorId") %>'>
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="">(none)</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

As I said above, the initial page displays just fine; the `DropDownList` has the right entries in it and the correct vendor is set to the correct value. Just clicking on the `Update` button causes the above error.

Here is the relevant part of the stack trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: A property named 'Vendor.VendorId' was not found on the entity during an insert, update, or delete operation.
>   Check to ensure that properties specified as binding expressions are
>   available to the data source.]
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ConvertProperties(IDictionary
>   values, PropertyDescriptorCollection propertyDescriptors,
>   ParameterCollection referenceParameters, Dictionary`2 convertedValues)
>   +263
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues) +256
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +95

I hope that is enough information!

Comment: I think I am doing more or less what this guy is doing:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc546554.aspx
(From 5:00 until 9:20), except using a FormView instead of a GridView.  Not sure what makes the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't the selectedvalue though be from the PartEntityDataSource perspective, because the  VendorEntityDataSource isn't binding the overall data bound control, you need to use `<%# Bind("VendorID") %>` instead.

HTH.

Comment: I think that might have been it.  I have another error in there, will let you know.

Comment: Awesome!  That did it!  There's an old joke with a punchline: "Cost of a piece of chalk: $0.49.  Knowledge of where to draw the X: $4,999.51."  Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, true :-)  Forgot the part type was the binding context, so it isn't needed.